# How to get the fitline equation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am wondering why the equation of `fitline` in opencv is this one:

```
t=atan2(2dxy,dx2-dy2)/2;
```

which is like this in math:

[image: equation inside opencv]

Why it is not this equation, which I got from my point of view:

```
t=atan2(dxy,dx2);
```

which is like this in math:

[image: equation which I got from my point of view]

Related definitions:

[image: related definitions]

Comment: what do your `2` even mean?

Comment: I paste some images to help understand